# (Rails) Test if user tries to get root directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is a script that get a directory from user. How to check if user tries to get more up level than public folder?

For example, I was tried to detect empty string, so if I enter `"?directory=/"` => I get into root directory. Than I tried to check if the way to public folder is in the path. Again => `"?directory=/home/user/app/public/../../../../../"` => and again I'm in the root.

How to test it and deny access?

Comment: It sounds like whatever you're trying to do is just asking to be exploited.

Comment: That's why I'm asking, It's an obvious security bug.

Comment: Is there another approach you can take that doesn't require passing the directory like that? What are you doing with it?

Comment: I'm writing web file manager. (I didn't find working solution). So, it will send requests with directory paths, than will be deletion requests, and I'm afraid to imagine, what could be if user get higher than public directory.

Comment: Found temporary solution, but I seems it is buggy.

    `if File.realpath(directory).to_s.length < File.join(Rails.public_path, CONFIG["filemanager"]["root_directory"]).to_s.length
          @test = 'ACHTUNG!!!'
    end`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def path_valid?(path, base = Rails.public_path)
  expanded_path_name = Pathname.new(path).realpath.to_s
  expanded_path_name.starts_with? base
end
```

`Pathname#realpath` will resolve a path to an absolute path, as well as do symlink resolution. This will let you test precisely where the path of the file to be operated on is, and ensure that it is inside a given path.